# React-Redux error Invalid prop `children` of type `object` supplied to `Provider`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am very much stumbling my way through learning how Redux works. I'm currently getting the following errors:

```
Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `children` of type `object` supplied to `Provider`, expected `function` 
Uncaught TypeError: children is not a function
```

My code is below -- is anyone able to spot why I'm getting this error?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as reducers from '../reducers/index';
import SassMeter from '../components/SassMeter';
import * as SassActions from '../actions/SassActions';
import _ from 'lodash'

const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <SassMeter />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

From what I understand, it's complaining that I'm passing an invalid prop to Provider, but all the examples I've seen follow the pattern I've followed there -- create the store using `createStore()`, then pass it in as props to the Provider, which wraps your root element. I feel like maybe I'm missing something to do with `connect` but I'm not sure what.

All help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You should most likely upgrade your version of `react-redux` and/or `react`.

In React < 0.14 and react-redux < 1.0.0, the Provider component only accepted a function as the `children` prop. This was a workaround to owner-based context propagation, which was deprecated in favor of parent-based context propagation in React 0.14. See [the corresponding doc](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/tree/499016ec1c100361580c671e08c8424ef26699ed#props) on the react-redux 1.0.0 README.